# Got caught for similar answers on an assignment

Tags: plagiarism, exams, cheating, homework

So recently my professor reported me and my colleague for cheating and reported both of us to the Board. We haven't heard from them yet, its been a week.

This was a class assignment for a masters course and it accounts for 15% of the grade. The plagiarism is about 30 - 35%.

Now, I've already apologised to the Prof saying that I had asked my colleague to help me because I was going to personal issues due to COVID as an international student. He has not replied to that email yet.

What can I expect next?

I'm really scared and I'm not sure what is going to happen. I'm already stressed about staying away from home during this crisis and now this.

Comment: How should this forum know what will happen? Maybe you will have to leave the university, maybe you fail the course. Maybe there are no consequences.

Comment: Have you learned something out of this incident? (sorry for acting like an a**, but it is important to.learn something from those kind of incidents).

Comment: Of course I have. Even if I'm not in the best state of mind to study, I should contact the professor first and let him know instead of asking someone else to help me solve it. No matter what, cheating is wrong.

Comment: So you did cheat. If you copied a third of the assignment from someone, then this is more than “asking for help”. You should’ve informed the lecturer about any personal difficulties instead of (frankly) copying someone else’s answers. In a fair world, the two of you can expect to get zero marks — at least for the 30% - 35% in question.

Comment: @Sensitive_Chapter: Okay, great. I am relieved. Sorry again

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as (1) we cannot know how your professor will handle this, and (2) there are lots of other substantively-similar questions already on this site. As others have said, cheating on a single assignment (as a first offense) usually results in a zero grade for the assignment. Penalties could be stricter since you are in a master's program, however.

Comment: @cag51. I'm so sorry, I posted this because all the other questions have been for bachelor or diploma. Wasn't sure how this would work for a masters degree. Wanted to know what I can expect so that I'm better prepared to mentally handle this situation. I'm really worried about the consequences of this. In my weakness due to my stress, I committed a stupid mistake and I really don't know how this is all going to pan out.

Comment: Just relax, don't take it too hard. You cannot do much about it now anyways.